# overloading >> operator for enum type(weekday)

Tags: c++

I compile my c++ code in Xcode, but it doesn't work. It seems that something wrong with my overloading `>>`  operator function that I don't know what it is!??!!!

And I also got the error "Variable 'd' is uninitialized when used here ". I want to cin `d` from user so that's why I can't understand this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum weekday{MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY};

weekday operator+(weekday day, int days){
    return weekday((int(day) + days) % 7);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
ostream &operator<<(ostream &ostrm, weekday day){
    switch(int(day)){
        case MONDAY:
            ostrm << "MONDAY";
            break;
        case TUESDAY:
            ostrm << "TUESDAY";
            break;
        case WEDNESDAY:
            ostrm << "WEDNESDAY";
            break;
        case THURSDAY:
            ostrm << "THURSDAY";
            break;
        case FRIDAY:
            ostrm << "FRIDAY";
            break;
        case SATURDAY:
            ostrm << "SATURDAY";
            break;
        case SUNDAY:
            ostrm << "SUNDAY";
            break;
        default:
            ostrm << "Somewhere inside the depth of time...";
    }
    return ostrm;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
istream &operator>>(istream &istrm, weekday day){
    switch(int(day)){
        case 0:
            istrm >> MONDAY;
            break;
        case 1:
            istrm >> TUESDAY;
            break;
        case 2:
            istrm >> WEDNESDAY;
            break;
        case 3:
            istrm >> THURSDAY;
            break;
        case 4:
            istrm >> FRIDAY;
            break;
        case 5:
            istrm >> SATURDAY;
            break;
        case 6:
            istrm >> SUNDAY;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Your input is not valid..." << endl;
    }
    return istrm;
}
//---------------------------------------------
int main(){
    cout << "Enter the day: ";
    weekday d;
    cin >> d;
    d = d + 16;

    cout << d << endl;       
}
```

Comment: There is no overloading in C, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Read a string or integer, and convert it to the enum.

Comment: `istrm >> MONDAY;`: think about what this would do. It's a bit like `istrm >> 42;`.

Comment: `istrm >> MONDAY;`  doesnt make much sense. You want to read a value from `istrm` and store it somewhere. What you have is `istream >>` and then...the value that you expect to read ...?...

Comment: "it doesn't work" and "something wrong with my overloading >> operator function" are not good problem descriptions. Be clear with exactly what's happening and exactly what errors you get. Ideally, also reduce your code examples to [mcve]s. If the problem is with input, there's no need for the whole output half of the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: `istream &istrm, weekday day` mmm... I don't see much point in reading into a local function parameter.

Comment: @S.Safinia _"would you pleas tell me what is wrong with my function parameters?"_ Pass them as reference parameters as explained in that duplicate FAQ I have linked above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second paramater is output value, you need to assign into it and pass it by reference:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &istrm, weekday &day){
    int a;
    istrm >> a;
    switch(a){
        case 0:
            day = MONDAY;
            break;
        case 1:
            day = TUESDAY;
            break;
        case 2:
            day = WEDNESDAY;
            break;
        case 3:
            day = THURSDAY;
            break;
        case 4:
            day = FRIDAY;
            break;
        case 5:
            day = SATURDAY;
            break;
        case 6:
            day =  SUNDAY;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Your input is not valid..." << endl;
    }
    return istrm;
}
//---------------------------------------------
int main(){
    cout << "Enter the day: ";
    weekday d;
    cin >> d;
    // d = d + 16;

    cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, now it compiles!